# How important is disability insurance, e.g. long-term, LTD? Employer offers none

Tags: insurance, employment

How important is it to have disability insurance? My employer does not provide it. I work in the web development business.

Comment: One clarification:  Does your employer provide short-term disability insurance but *not* long-term, or **neither** form of disability insurance?

Comment: how old are you, do you have children etc, where do you live, e.g. what are the disability benfits you could get, what commitments do you have, etc....

Comment: My employer does not provide any type of insurance at all. I have a long-term disability insurance policy. I was just checking to make sure it was an important thing to put my money towards.  Thanks for everyone's answers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The reason to have disability insurance is to replace your income if you become disabled and are no longer able to work.  For this purpose, it is kind of similar to life insurance where you want to replace your income to take care of people that depend on your income if you die, but now you are included in the people that depend on your income.

If your employer doesn't provide any disability insurance then it would be wise to look for some Long Term disability insurance.  Short Term disability is more expensive than long term and it is USUALLY better and cheaper to have a good emergency fund to provide for a short term disability such as being sick for a month and not able to work than to buy short-term.

As a web developer - you should be able to get long term disability insurance at a reasonable cost, unless you have some dangerous hobbies like forest fire fighting or shark juggling.

Comment: +1 Good answer.  Up-vote for the shark juggling example. :-)

Comment: If you are a member of a professional society (e.g. IEEE or ACM), check whether they offer long-term disability insurance and whether the rates are competitive. Also, the longer the period before the insurance payout starts after the disability commences, the smaller the premium. If you have a six-month emergency fund put away, having a policy that starts paying out three or four months after disability forces you to stop working may be a better buy.

Answer (score 4):

*(Oops - I had been meaning to come back to this Q. sooner. Just saw my reminder, so here goes.)*

Shortly before this question was asked, I actually read a good blog post on the subject of disability insurance at **[Evolution of Wealth - 7 Ways Your Group Disability Will Fail.](http://evolutionofwealth.com/2010/01/group-disability-fail/)**  I know the OP doesn't have group disability (and hence the question), but the reason I'm highlighting it is:

**Even somebody *with* a group disability policy from their employer may want to consider supplementing it with an individual policy that has better coverage.**

In my case, the reason I opted for an individual policy was due to point #6 from the post:

> ... ***ways that group disability coverage will fail you:***
>
> ...  [etc]
>
> 6) **You can go work somewhere else.**
>   With disability insurance there is a
>   feature called own-occupation.  This
>   means that you are unable to perform
>   the duties of your specific occupation
>   even if you are able to work in an
>   other occupation.  Good group
>   disability coverage will cover your
>   own-occupation for a period of 2 years
>   after that if you can work anywhere
>   (yes, even McDonald’s) then you
>   receive no more benefits.  Notice I
>   said ‘good’ coverage, a lot of
>   policies don’t even have the
>   own-occupation benefit. ...

**I made sure my own individual LTD policy included coverage of own-occupation until age 65.**  So, do pay attention to the specific features and limitations of LTD policies when shopping for one.

Comment: +1 Whoa, that stipulation is good to be aware of. Here's [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disability_insurance#What_if_the_beneficiary_is_not_totally_disabled.2C_but_only_partially.3F) on the topic of own occupation

Answer (score 1):

(My wife works for an insurance broker in the US, so take that grain of salt with my answer)

Disability insurance covers your income should you be unable to work.  Some disability will be paid before social security (so you get both incomes) and some will be paid after (so your insurance will fill whatever gap SS leaves)

Everybody in the US gets Social Security, which has a disability provision you can use.  The additional disability insurance is a good idea for people with a family who will rely on your income for the future, or even for yourself should you work in a dangerous position.

My family has it, and we consider it essential for our well being, but I consider insurance on many things a necessity not a luxury.  (except pet insurance, I find that to be a luxury.)

Comment: Expanding on that a bit, one caveat on Social Security disability is that you must be completely unable to work in any field. No matter your previous career, if you can still do any minimum-wage job of any kind you can't get social security. Also, Social Security disability payments are much lower than your previous income. The bottom line is that Social Security doesn't protect your family from a huge drop in living standard, so it's still worth getting private insurance.